# why does clicking action of button from SharePoint user control refresh/reload the entire page?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I Am creating a SharePoint user control,in which I have to use buttons and the c# code so I used `asp:button` but when am deploying control on page to test then and after  clicking on button  this click action reload/refresh he entire page,which I dont want.

So how can I prevent page from getting refresh after clicking button?

Comment: refer and use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**If you're on the page where Minimal Download Strategy (aka MDS, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx) for a first definition) is used (default behavior on a Team site)**, then it means your control is not MDS-compatible. As soon as your control becomes MDS-aware, all the MDS infrastructure will take care of "not reloading the entire page when you navigate" for you.
You need at least to mark it with the `MdsCompliant` attribute:

```
[MdsCompliant(true)]
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...
```

See e.g. [this blog post](http://steve.thelineberrys.com/gotchas-using-custom-web-parts-and-the-minimal-download-strategy/) by Steve Lineberry for more info.

**If you're on a Publishing site where MDS is not enabled, what you want is to change the default behavior of ASP.NET buttons** (that perform actual postbacks to the server when an event happens on the client, like the button click).
This is then a pure ASP.NET question (i.e. not SharePoint specific): how to prevent a user action to trigger an actual postback with the page being reloaded. The answer is called "Ajax". Ajax allows you to "intercept" user actions client-side and to emit "background" HTTP request to the server (with the mean of JavaScrip code).
This technique is very well and very commonly described in various articles (note that it's not even ASP.NET-specific as it's used everywhere on the Web, independantly of the technology used by the server).
You can look [here](http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/02/calling-asp-net-code-behind-using-jquery-ajax-simple-complete-example/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855747/jquery-asp-net-button-click-event-via-ajax), [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/769238/call-server-side-code-using-asp-net-ajax-and-jquer), or at *a lot* of [other articles](https://www.google.fr/search?q=asp.net%20ajax%20button%20click).

Comment: i tried these both approaches but none of them worked,can you suggest some others?

Comment: What did you try exactly? What do you mean by "not working"? Are you in a MDS site or not? The Ajax approach is not something that may or may not work. It's a concept that is (almost) always implementable, despite difficulties you may encounter depending on your context...

Comment: no am not in MDS site